# How to Identify the First and Last Non Zero Value in the Column and return both the location of both in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I check the first and last non zero values in the columns and return its location from the data frame.

Attached is the data Frame I am working with.

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|551` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 
957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 
1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 1850, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 
33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any suggestions for finding the location based on the check would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first and last location of the non zero value can be done like this.

```
df <- structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
                                      "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
                                      "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
                                      "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
                                      "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
                                      "2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
                                      "2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
                                      "2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
                                      "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
                                      "2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|551` = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 
                                                                                               957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 
                                                                                               1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 1850, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 
                                                                                               33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`This will get you the location of all non zero values in the column. There since the column is 2` 
`You can set the column number to anything which you want based on the data frame`

```
which(df[,2]!=0,arr.ind = T)
```

`This will return value in the correct order, so just using head and tail to get the first and last value`

```
head(which(df[,2]!=0,arr.ind = T),1)
```

`If you want this in character or double you can make the conversion like this`

```
First_Value <- as.double(head(which(df[,2]!=0,arr.ind = T),1))  
Last_Value <- as.double(tail(which(df[,2]!=0,arr.ind = T),1))
```

`Results of the this`

```
First_Value
[1] 10  1
> Last_Value
[1] 40  1
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R perhaps something like this:

```r
# first non-zero
# which.min() for booleans is the 1st FALSE

first_nz <- which.min(df$`XYZ|551` == 0)
df[first_nz,]
#>    Row Labels XYZ|551
#> 10 2019-10-01     206

# last non-zero
# first reverse dataframe rows
df_rev <- df[nrow(df):1,]
# then same as before, but extract just the matching `Row Labels`
(last_nz_rowlbl <- df_rev$`Row Labels`[which.min(df_rev$`XYZ|551` == 0)])
#> [1] "2022-04-01"

last_nz <- which(df$`Row Labels` == last_nz_rowlbl)
df[last_nz,]
#>    Row Labels XYZ|551
#> 40 2022-04-01      33

# location (row index) of first non-zero:
first_nz
#> [1] 10
# location (row index) of last non-zero:
last_nz
#> [1] 40
```

Input:

```r
df <- structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
                                "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
                                "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
                                "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
                                "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
                                "2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
                                "2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
                                "2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
                                "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
                                "2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|551` = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 
                                                                                         957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 
                                                                                         1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 1850, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 
                                                                                         33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The expecation is to get the location number not the value in the location. Suppose in the first non 0 value is 10th, the expected result is to get [10,1].

Comment: Updated the answer. Though stating *"[10,1]"* seems to hint that the column index is also unknown, there indeed can be any number of columns that should be checked and first & last non-zeor location may or may not origin from the same column?  If that's the case, perhaps update the sample dataset to include few more columns and specify the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
library(tidyverse)

some_data <- structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
                                "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
                                "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
                                "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
                                "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
                                "2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
                                "2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
                                "2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
                                "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
                                "2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|551` = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 
                                                                                         957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 
                                                                                         1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 1850, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 
                                                                                         33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))

first_and_last_non_zero_of_column <- function(df, var,
                                              rowlabel_var = "Row Labels") {
  if (identical(var, rowlabel_var)) {
    return(NULL)
  }

  nonzero <- select(
    df,
    {{ rowlabel_var }},
    {{ var }}
  ) |> filter(!!sym(var) > 0)
  enframe(list(
    first = slice_head(nonzero, n = 1),
    last = slice_tail(nonzero, n = 1)
  ), name = "order") |>
    unnest_wider(col = value) |>
    pivot_longer(
      cols = var,
      names_to = "variable_name"
    )
}

first_and_last_non_zero_of_column(some_data, "XYZ|551")

# if you have more than one variable to check
map_dfr(
  names(some_data),
  ~ first_and_last_non_zero_of_column(
    df = some_data,
    var = .x
  )
)
```